# MySQL CSV import: datetime value

Tags: mysql, csv

I have been banging my head against a wall trying to import datetime values from a .csv file.

Here's the import statement.

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myData.csv' 
                INTO TABLE equity_last_import
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                (equity,last,@last_date) 
                SET last_date = STR_TO_DATE( @last_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')`

Here's a sample of the data:

```
4108,48.74,"2013-09-16 16:15:04"
4249,8.1,"2013-09-16 16:15:04"
4197,3.81,"2013-09-16 17:20:00"
4139,26.81,"2013-09-16 16:15:04"
4218,24.83,"2013-09-16 17:20:00"
4260,79.72,"2013-09-16 16:15:04"
4270,450.12,"2013-09-16 17:20:00"
4242,30.38,"2013-09-16 16:15:04"
4193,1.42,"2013-09-16 16:15:04"
4134,3.77,"2013-09-16 16:15:04"
```

I am able to import date values using `STR_TO_DATE()` but I not able to get datetime values to import.  I have tried several different date formats other than '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' and I always get a null datetime [0000-00-00 00:00:00].  I have also tried not using `STR_TO_DATE()`, since the string is in the default MySQL datetime format.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The date in your data file is already in a format MySQL should natively understand. It's just enclosed in double quotes. You need to tell `LOAD DATA INFILE` how to deal with the quotes. Try something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myData.csv'
INTO TABLE equity_last_import
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(equity,last,last_date)
```

### Update:

Since you've said it doesn't work, I created a test table and verified that it does work. Here's the proof:

I've highlighted your csv data from the question and pasted into a new file called `myData.csv` in my system's `/tmp` folder. Then I connected to the mysql console, switched to the `test` database and ran the following:

```
mysql> create table equity_last_import (equity int, last decimal(10,2), last_date datetime) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/myData.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE equity_last_import
    -> FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> (equity,last,last_date);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from equity_last_import;
+--------+--------+---------------------+
| equity | last   | last_date           |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
|   4108 |  48.74 | 2013-09-16 16:15:04 |
|   4249 |   8.10 | 2013-09-16 16:15:04 |
|   4197 |   3.81 | 2013-09-16 17:20:00 |
|   4139 |  26.81 | 2013-09-16 16:15:04 |
|   4218 |  24.83 | 2013-09-16 17:20:00 |
|   4260 |  79.72 | 2013-09-16 16:15:04 |
|   4270 | 450.12 | 2013-09-16 17:20:00 |
|   4242 |  30.38 | 2013-09-16 16:15:04 |
|   4193 |   1.42 | 2013-09-16 16:15:04 |
|   4134 |   3.77 | 2013-09-16 16:15:04 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See? It works perfectly.

### Another Update:

You've specified that you're getting the following error now:

```
Out of range value for column 'last_date' at row 1
```

Does your CSV file have a header? If so, you may want to add `IGNORE 1 LINES` to your `LOAD DATA INFILE` command to tell MySQL to skip over the header.

Comment: I've tried.  Doesn't work. " I have also tried not using STR_TO_DATE(), since the string is in the default MySQL datetime format. "

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist: Sure does. I tested it and added my test sql to my answer.

Comment: My database is Amazon RDS MySQL 5.1, and it doesn't work. I'll try running it on a different version of MySQL and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist: Ahh. You're running an Amazon RDS instance. In that case you won't have access to the local disk to place your CSV file. You need to remove the work `LOCAL` from your `LOAD DATA INFILE` command and you should be all set. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `LOCAL` lets one upload the CSV from a client, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data-local.html . I've tried on MySQL 5.5 without success but now I get warnings.  `Out of range value for column 'last_date' at row 1`

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist: Ahh. I had the `LOCAL` setting backwards. It's local from the client's perspective, not the server's perspective. My mistake. I guess it's been a while. In regards to the error message you've posted; Does your CSV file have a header? If so, you may want to try adding `IGNORE 1 LINES` to tell MySQL to skip over the header line. I've updated my answer with this suggestion.

Comment: I end up converting the datetime to a timestamp before write the CSV.  Then covert it back to a datetime during import with `SET last_date = FROM_UNIXTIME( @last_date )` .  I don't know why it doesn't work as we expect.

Answer (score 22):

I ran into the same problem. I fixed it by changing the format for the date column in my CSV file to match the MySQL datetime format.

1. Open CSV in Excel.
2. Highlight the column.
3. Right-click on the column.
4. Click on `Format Cells`.
5. Pick `Custom`.
6. Use `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` in the `Type` field.
7. Click `ok`

My CSV successfully imported after I changed the datetime format as above.

Comment: This worked great. I'm writing JS using moment, so the formatting was like so: `moment(value).format('YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss')`

Answer (score 2):

Pulled my hair out over this also because I'm not importing in the above suggested way.

Workaround: Created a temporary field temp_date of type "VARCHAR" on your import table and have no problems loading the data. I then was able to perform an update on my date column which is of type date.

```
    update table
    set date = temp_date
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same trouble and here's what I discovered, I think it might help you

The problem regards a GMT conflict:
The database I was extracting the .csv file was on GMT 00:00, so there wasn't daylight saving time.

My local server (which was the one I was trying to insert the .csv file) was running on my computer (system's) GMT, by default. In my case it was  GMT -3, which is affected by daylight saving time.

SQL has a special way to deal with daylight saving time, it ignores the exact date and time when the daylight saving time starts to happen. In my case, it was october 20 and all the records between 00 and 1 AM of that day simply weren't recognized by the server, even if the format was correct, because they simply 'didn't exist' (see more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#i1006760)). This was affecting all timestamp records, not only the specifics of daylight saving time.

My solution was to set the local server to GMT +00, before creating the new table and import the .csv, using

```
SET time_zone='+00:00';
```

And then when I imported the .csv file all the records were read properly. I think if you set the time zone equal to the one that generated the .csv file should work!

Answer (score 0):

Open CSV in Excel.
Highlight the column.
Right-click on the column.
Click on Format Cells.
Pick Custom.
Use same format as SQL date format yyyy-mm-dd
Click ok and save
it's working fine for me