# PHP Date column does not populate from csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file into a table. When I run the query the date_altered column does not populate properly.

Insert query:

```
xtc_db_query("
        LOAD DATA INFILE '".$bpmand."'
        INTO TABLE bpmand_update
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
        (@skip, customers_id, @skip, @skip, date_altered, @skip)
        ");
```

Other info -

Table creation:

```
$createtable = '    
        CREATE TABLE bpmand_update
        (
        orders_id int(11),
        customers_id int(11),
        bonuspoints_received int(11),
        bonuspoints_spent int(11),
        current_bonuspoints int(11),
        date_altered datetime,
        comment varchar(50));';
    xtc_db_query($createtable);
```

The csv file looks like:

```
"1260","13-11-2013 11:45:45"
"5222","09-01-2014 11:45:45"
```

Edit:
If I got to phpmyadmin and run

```
INSERT INTO bpmand_update (customers_id, date_altered) VALUES ("1260","13-11-2013 11:45:45")
```

Everything is fine

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838000/mysql-csv-import-datetime-value

Comment: datetime format value should be `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: Ambiguous date format: is `09-01-2014` the 1st of September, or the 9th of January? `2014-01-09` format eliminates ambiguity, it's the 9th of January

Comment: The date format is fine

Comment: @user986959  The date format clearly __isn't__ fine, otherwise you wouldn't have this problem

Comment: @MarkBaker, yes, you are right

Comment: Are we talking about MySQL?

Comment: @akirk - with the reference in the question to phpmyadmin, I'd say definitely yes

Comment: @MarkBaker ah, that's a good hint indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL needs the date to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, you have it as `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`. So you need to modify your SQL statement anlong the lines of [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10102707/578588) as follows:

```
    LOAD DATA INFILE '".$bpmand."'
    INTO TABLE bpmand_update
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (@skip, customers_id, @skip, @skip, @date, @skip)
    SET date_altered = STR_TO_DATE(@date,'%d-%m-%Y %H-%i-%s')
```

Comment: +1 for actually providing a simple-to-implement solution rather than simply identifying the problem

Answer (score 1):

In your CSV file datetime value should be in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` instead of `13-11-2013 11:45:45`. So you need convert the date value as MySQL accepted format

**DATETIME** values in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html