# Inserting .csv file into mysql db Java: DATETIME format column not imported successfully

Tags: java, mysql, csv, datetime

The `.csv` file that I'm trying to import has a `DATETIME` column called `test_date` that's behaving a bit weirdly. The output in the mySQL table is all `00:00:00 00:00`.

It's shown in notepad as `"2017-03-25 00:00:01"` where it seems the `""` surrounding the date-time value is the crucial factor here.

Facts of the problem:

1. MySQL table's corresponding column is of the type `DATETIME`
2. I have used `+"SET test_date = STR_TO_DATE(@var2, '%d/%m/%Y %k:%i')"` to handle incorrect date-time formats
3. All other `.csv` docs where the date-time column was stored **without** `""` were successfully imported.
4. I use the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command on my IDE's Java code as shown:

   ```
   String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + file
       + "' INTO TABLE source_data_android_cell CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
       + "ENCLOSED BY '\"'" + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  " + "IGNORE 1 LINES(@var1...)"
       + "SET test_date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d/%m/%Y %k:%i')";
   ```

I have no control over how the `.csv` files are created or stored so what are the possible remedies to my code on my end?

UPDATED:

As suggested by Maurice, I endeavoured to find out how to read a `.csv` file and store it into an array.

Forgive my shameless googling skills, but I've managed to source together the following:

```
public void processCSVFile(String filePath){
    try(BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)))){
        //Create two lists to hold name and height.
        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> heightList = new ArrayList<>();

        String eachLine = "";
        /*
         * Read until you hit end of file.
         */
        while((eachLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null){
            /*
             * As it is CSV file, split each line at ","
             */
            String[] nameAndHeightPair = eachLine.split(",");

            /*
             * Add each item into respective lists.
             */
            nameList.add(nameAndHeightPair[0]);
            heightList.add(Integer.parseInt(nameAndHeightPair[1]));
        }

        /*
         * If you are very specific, you can convert these
         * ArrayList to arrays here.
         */
    }catch(IOException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The thing is, how do I tweak the code to handle `.csv` files where info is stored as `"...", "..."` to handle the `""` containment?

Comment: Sure: read the csv line by line, and INSERT each row.

Comment: ah damn, i was hoping to avoid having to do that =/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an answer to this question here: [MySQL CSV import: datetime value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838000/mysql-csv-import-datetime-value?rq=1)

Basically what my code wasn't doing was handling the " separators well. All i needed was to rearrange the command, curiously enough and it worked

Changing my LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command to the below seemed to do the trick:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'ios_Data.csv'
INTO TABLE ios_import
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(test_date)
```

Use of `+"SET test_date = STR_TO_DATE(@var2, '%d/%m/%Y %k:%i')"` is also not needed, to my surprise.